# Where and how does Windows XP store wep/wpa keys?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Like the title says Where and How (i.e. if encrypted, with what method) does Windows XP store WEP/WPA Keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706987(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it couldn't help you; I was only answering the question asked here (not the "main question").

But the link you specify has the information about the wep/wpa keys if I'm not mistaken, so you probably have figured it out and should close this questions if that's the case.

Comment: No I have not found how, I don't know the win32API so I don't know how to use that info in python.